# MySQL multi-Table sync

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers, synchronization

I like to sync the "Table" with all "subtable",

1. if records , let us say in "subtable 1" (key: "customer name"="customer 1"),  are inserted/updated/deleted, I like to update "Table" (key: "customer name"="customer 1")
2. if records, which are only associated with "customer 1" in "Table" , are inserted/updated/deleted , I like to only update "subtable 1" (key: "customer name"="customer 1").

please refer to this picture:
[image]

What could I do to achieve it? trigger or procedure or anything else?

Welcome any ideas.

---

Here is entire scenario.
[image]
Story: I have many remote customers. on their pcs, I install mysql and set it as "master" which gathers data that is just associated with this specific customer. Also in my office, I have a central MySQL database which is set as "slave" or "Master". I try to setup MySQL replication between the central MySql database(in my office) and all my remote customers'.

the details are listed below.

1. data from customers is individual. customer just has their own data.
2. customers and I share the same database schema
3. all data from customers' tables (DailyWeights) are saved into the corresponding table(DailyWeights) on the central database

The requirements:

The "UP" replication, from customers to central database, is ok. I mean, if I set my solution as multi-source pattern, this can be doable, no problem. But, if I modify some records, let us say "Customer 1" , in DailyWeights table on central database, I want just corresponding DailyWeights table on "Customer 1" is updated with the modified data. Not to dump all data from DailyWeights table on central database to "Customer 1". That is, I want that just customer 1 data is synchronized other than the others, because of data security.

My question is: is view still ok?

Welcome any feedback. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you define your `table` as a VIEW that takes the UNION ALL of your various subtables, or maybe each subtable as a VIEW of the `table`?  Then everything will be in sync automatically.

Comment: Use a view.  Don't create "table", just `union` the subtables together.